# Showing error while passing asset images in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am just a beginner in a flutter. I am trying to pass asset images to other class but I am getting error.
here is my code

main.dart file

```
        
     class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
             ListInfo(photo:"assets\images\apple.jpg",name:"Apple");
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   );
                 }
               }
```

Listinfo class

```
     class ListInfo
     {
     final String photo;
     final String name;
     ListInfo({this.photo, this.name});
     }
```

ListImages class

```
        class ListImages extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
         ListInfo info = new ListInfo();
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(info.photo),
            ),
            Text(
              info.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sorry for asking such a basic question. but I am unable to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add asset on `pubspec.yaml`

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

 assets:
  -assets\images\apple.jpg
  -assets\images\orange.jpg
```

Then update with `pub get`

Use `Image.asset('assets\images\apple.jpg')` to add the image as widget in your list

```
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset('assets\images\apple.jpg',),
        Text(
          info.name,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
        ),

        Image.asset('assets\images\orange.jpg',),
        Text(
          info.name,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: do you hava list of images

Comment: if more images, then add it inside childeren